# Setting up a VPN on a Surface 2

Tags: windows-8.1, vpn, microsoft-surface

For those not in the know, Surface 2 is one of the few Microsoft tablet & laptops that use the ARM architecture. The combination of a full Windows OS (8.1 RT & 10) & ARM being rare, few ever produce software for these odd devices. That & the fact that Microsoft only allows signed executables to run (Windows products + updates or those from Microsoft Store), really prohibits installation of so many packages.

This is true with trying to setup a VPN. Most VPN providers ask the client to run a installer to configure a VPN connection. The combination of these third party installers being unsigned by Microsoft & the trouble of having to provide binaries that are for Windows on ARM, makes the VPNs providers not even bothering with the installer I need.

So how do I go about this? Can I manually configure the VPN as the installer would? If so, is there a way to work out what the installer does? Should I get in touch with tech support instead? Can you guys name VPN providers where I could do this approach? It'll be great if the VPN is free.

Comment: Does this help? https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/pages/client-support/windows8.1-l2tp

Comment: @SQLTemp: Pretty good, but I'm such a cheapstake that i'm holding out for someone to suggest a free VPN that I can do manually. If it exists.

Comment: what’s your correct vpn provider? All steps will be the same to setup on windows. I personally wouldnt recommend a free VPN to anyone

Comment: Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they become outdated quickly and attract opinion-based answers. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve

Comment: What I used to have, factually without recommending it, was ExpressVPN. I suppose practically speaking, all the installers do, one can do manually. That's why I asked is if there was a way (a log, perhaps?) to know what an installer was doing while being run on a desktop Windows & then reproduce that on this old Surface 2.